# MySql.Data can't connect to AWS Aurora

Tags: .net-core, amazon-aurora, mysql.data, aws-aurora-serverless

I have a really weird connection problem between C# .net core and AWS Aurora Serverless (MySql).  I have a really simple web API that I'm using for testing.  One of my endpoints is really simple to get the first row of one table:

```
        string cnString = "myConnectionString";
        string returnData = "";

        using (MySqlConnection cnData = new MySqlConnection(cnString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmdData = new MySqlCommand("SELECT userName FROM users LIMIT 1", cnData))
            {
                await cnData.OpenAsync();
                await cmdData.ExecuteScalarAsync();

                returnData = (string)cmdData.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }

        return Ok(returnData);
```

I have the MySql.Data NuGet package installed.  When I deploy the package, I get an error: **Unable to connect to to any of the specified MySQL hosts. (Sequence contains more than one matching element)**

If I uninstall the MySql.Data package and install the MySqlConnector package, then there is no error and everything works properly.  There are no changes to the code or connection string.  The only thing I change is the NuGet package.

I don't think it matters, but my app is deployed to an Amazon Linux EC2 instance.

Does anyone know why the MySql.Data package doesn't work?  For my deployment, I need that package and I can't use the MySqlConnector package.

Comment: You tested both packages in the same environment? i.e. both on your local machine and ec2? 100% sure it's a not a security group issue?

Comment: Both packages, same environment, same code, same server, same local machine.  Basically, it runs with one package and not the actual Oracle package.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having the same problem, there is an issue in the MySql.Data package.

I suspect that it is related to this known bug:
[MySql #97448](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97448)

The way that I read it is this:  the Aurora Cluster uses multiple IP addresses, so the Sequence contains more than 1 element error is thrown.  (The multiple elements are IP addresses in the TcpStream().

There is no fix that I saw, but I found a workaround that downgrading the package to 8.0.16 fixes the problem.